# Page Load Time With Selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver, performance-testing, page-load-time

We are trying to find the page load time with Selenium WebDriver for a website. We want to get the page load time for multiple screens/pages in the website, say the login and after login , the main screen and so on.

Our driver.get() call is for the login URL,

```
driver.get("https://<website root>/login")
```

I am trying this piece of code twice, first when the login page is loaded and again after the login button is clicked for the main page to load.

```
long pageLoadTime = (Long) driver.executeScript("return (window.performance.timing.loadEventEnd-window.performance.timing.responseStart)" );
```

Both times we get the same pageLoadTime. Is the window.performance object never refreshed? I do understand what is happening. How do we get the load time for different screens in the test flow.

Comment: are you calling this from a single method or only the same line written twice?

Comment: Same line written in 2 different places, once after the login page is loaded and again when the main page is loaded

Comment: Is it possible that the application under test uses Angular or React framework? Does the browser window reloads after login to a different URL, or the window URL stays the same even after login?

Comment: The URL path stays the same but the fragment changes

Comment: That is probably the issue here. As per the browser, the page load has been completed but the application keeps loading page elements using AJAX within the same page. So, when you query the load time, it returns the same number. For your application, Selenium might not be the right tool to measure performance. If possible try using LoadNinja/JMeter/LoadRunner.

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

startTime = time.time()

driver.get("https://google.com/")
#Your element
inputElem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="tsf"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/input')
#implicitly_wait means, wait until the element is found
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
finishTime = time.time()

print(finishTime-startTime)
```

This works. Select an element from website and wait load of element.

Answer (score 0):

Try refreshing the current page once before executing any action.
driver.navigate().refresh();

This should solve your problem.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.